# How can I include slf4j-api, logback and custom implementation of slf4j.impl in OSGI?

Tags: java, osgi, slf4j, logback

I've previously implemented OSGI logging to files, using slf4j-api, logback-core and logback-classic bundles.

I'd now like to intercept log calls in a seperate bundle (to show them in a webpage servlet). This tutorial at [this blog](http://blog.kornr.net/index.php/2008/12/18/osgi-logging-putting-it-all-together) suggested building a custom implementation of org.slf4j.impl to pass on the messages to the log service. (This worked great!)

The problem I have is that I'd also like to save log messages to a file using logback and our custom implementation of org.slf4j.impl is a bundle in OSGI preventing the logback implementation of org.slf4j.impl being used.

I think this may be because in the tutorial the custom implementation of org.slf4j.impl and slf4j-api are embedded as dependencies and not installed as bundles. However when I try this with

```
<Embed-Dependency>slf4j.api_1.7.2.jar, logbackadapter.jar;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```

Slf4j-api still gets installed as a bundle. Does anyone know how to embed slf4j-api in a bundle to prevent it from using the exported org.slf4j.impl provided by logback?

Thanks for your help,

Brian

p.s. The full pom element is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>


   <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>
        <Export-Package></Export-Package>
        <Private-Package>${bundle.namespace}.internal.*</Private-Package>
        <Embed-Dependency>slf4j.api_1.7.2.jar;logbackadapter.jar;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
      </instructions>
   </configuraiton>
</plugin>
```

And the dependency element is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using Pax-Logging, this provides you all you need for logging. Only "drawback", depending on how you look at it, it's configured by std. log4j property file, since it uses the ConfigurationAdmin Service for this. Besides that it helps you a lot with all kinds of different loggin frameworks, log4j, slf4j, jul etc...

[Pax-Logging](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxlogging/Pax+Logging)

Comment: Hi Achim, thanks for the reponse. My understanding of pax-logging from   [this blog on the pax logging service](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.ops4j.general/11753) is that you can't register for logging events via the log service, so we wouldn't be able to intercept them in our servlet.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood that thread, cause Pax-Loggin is compliant to the osgi spec regarding Log-Service. Thous it doesn't need to register for logging events, it produces those. Your servlet just needs to register as a "Log-service-listener". The Felix Web-Console does this already, you might give it a look.

Comment: Hi Achim, I just tried this with pax-logging. Although the logservice messages are read by the servlet my slf4j log messages go straight to pax-logging. Our servlet needs to capture all log messages, slf4j and OSGI messages. Does pax logging make the slf4j messages available via an OSGI service interface? (I think the blog suggests writing a custom appender for this)

Comment: Depending on your setup you might be interested in taking a look at Apache Karaf, it's a OSGi container with everything configured out of the box to run smoothly. That said there is also a configuration file available that might be of interest for you. You need to configure the logging correctly. 
Following is used in Karaf: 
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, out, osgi:*

To my knowledge the last "logger" is used to send all logging statements to the log-service.